# url structure of internal websites

Tags: windows, linux, url, dns, debian

I would like to have a particular url structure of my company dev server.
we got a few websites, and I'm putting them on 1 server, but each websites can access to the same libs and config files making it easy to add another website in the future.
the URL structure that I want is like this :

```
htp://internalFolder.devName.internalUrl/

htp://www.mywebsite.com.project.web.devname.company.com/index.php
```

the folder structure is like this :

```
/home/devname/project/lib/

/home/devname/project/config/

/home/devname/project/web/www.mywebsite.com/

/home/devname/project/web/www.website2.com/
```

...
the url must access to those folders, and if the dev does a temporary folder in his folder he can access to it :

```
/home/devname/temp/

htp://temp.devname.company.com/
```

I got no idea how to do that... I got a DNS server in Windows Server 2008 and my dev server on Debian, if possible I do the linux server as secondary DNS or something like that.
I know it's possible cause it was the structure of my ex company, and it was really good.

Thanks a lot for your reply's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did another way finally... I hired someone but he gave up, so I do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

If they're all to be run from the same webserver, it doesn't have much to do with DNS (as long as you can get all of those URLs to the IP of the same webserver.

In apache, these different sites are known as [Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/).

Comment: but in my local if I type htp://dev.company.com, I'm redirected to the server, but if I type htp://anythingElse.dev.company.com it doesn't send me anywhere...